# Apply vignette in Krita

Tags: krita, vignette

Is there a way to apply a vignette effect onto an image in Krita?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because because you've shown no effort and requesting a plugin isn't in the scope with this site.  If you can make an [edit] to include an image of what you're talking about and remove the plugin suggestion then we can look into re-opening your question.

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ Hope I've shown enough effort this time by editing the question, hopefully to your likings. Please, as promised, do consider removing the "closed" death blow of your virtual lightsaber, and maybe remedy your downvote while at it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Krita is an excellent digital drawing/painting application, but it wouldn't be my first choice for editing photographs, although it does have basic photo editing tools that can be used. It can certainly be done.

1. Choose Black as the foreground colour
2. Duplicate the image layer
3. Make an elliptical selection
4. Select > Feather selection, and choose however many pixels you want to feather it by
5. Select > Invert selection
6. Edit > Fill with foreground colour

Krita is very slow/laggy when I try to to do this on Windows, might be better in Linux however.

You might be better using a different application, such as GIMP. In GIMP open an image and click Tools > GEGL Operation > scroll down the list and select Vignette, then move the sliders as required. This is almost instant, and there's a live preview. Also you can apply the GEGL Vignette filter on a transparent layer instead, then reduce the opacity if required, or apply Gaussian blur.

Comment: Hi, I wasn't aware that GIMP had the ability. Will try that. Thank you!